# Projection from Mongo query format to java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this Aggregation Mongo query and I dont know how to write the Projection part in Java. Could you please help me with that?

```
db.getCollection("motion").aggregate(
[
    { 
        "$match" : { 
            "type" : "NON_PERIODIC_MOTION", 
            "createdAt" : { 
                "$gte" : ISODate("2020-01-24T23:00:00.000+0000")
            }, 
            "minAccAmount" : { 
                "$gte" : 1000.0
            }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$limit" : 200.0
    }, 
    { 
        "$project" : { 
            "amount" : 1.0, 
            "createdAt" : 1.0, 
            "motionExternalId" : 1.0, 
            "motionRef" : 1.0
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$sort" : { 
            "amount" : 1.0
        }
    }
], 
{ 
    "allowDiskUse" : false
}
);
```

This is the code for the Match operation part.

```
Criteria criterias = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where(Motion.ACCELERATION).gte(minAccAmount)
        .and(Motion.TYPE).is(MotionTypeEnum.NON_PERIODIC_MOTION)
        .and("createdAt").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));
MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criteria);
```

Comment: The MongoDB query code you had posted with `find` is _not_ an aggregation operation, but your Java code is. `MongoTemplate` has `find` as well as `aggregate` methods.

Comment: Posted correct query

Comment: Projection is built using the [Aggregation.project()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html#project-java.lang.String...-) method. The method is overloaded and accepts `Fields` or string filed names.as var-args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
...

@Autowired
protected MongoOperations operations;
...

Criteria criterias = Criteria
    .where(Motion.ACCELERATION).gte(minAccAmount)
    .and(Motion.TYPE).is(MotionTypeEnum.NON_PERIODIC_MOTION)
    .and("createdAt").gte(startDate).lte(endDate);
MatchOperation match = match(criterias);
LimitOperation limit = limit(300);
ProjectionOperation project = project("amount", "createdAt", "motionExternalId","motionRef");
SortOperation sort = sort(Sort.by("amount"));

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match, limit, project, sort)
    .withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions()
        .allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE)
        .build());

List<Motion> result = operations.aggregate(agg, 
    operations.getCollectionName(Motion.class), Motion.class).getMappedResults();
```